# Foundation Responsive Web Design

Tags: html, css, responsive-design, zurb-foundation

I'm experimenting with foundation. Link: http://foundation.zurb.com/docs/index.php

I've got a very simple Div:

```
<div style="background:url(gymBasketballHoops.jpg);height:100%;">&nbsp;</div>
```

When I set height to 190 px it says 190 no matter the browser size, but when I set height ot 100% it's only show 50 px of image. I use lots of stuff in my current site that is going to be a background image, but i also want those heights responsive. How do i accomplish this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
<div style="background:url(gymBasketballHoops.jpg);height:100%;">&nbsp;</div>
```

> When I set height to 190 px it says 190 no matter the browser size,
>   but when I set height ot 100% it's only show 50 px of image.

Without seeing the rest of your HTML/CSS, I cannot recommend anything further than the following...

`190px` is a fixed size and will be 190 pixels high no matter what browser or resolution.

`100%` is the size with respect to the outer container of the `div`, **not** its content.  If the outer container is 500 pixels high then your `<div>` will be 100 percent of that.

Since the `<div>` is empty except for the `&nbsp;`, you have to set a size or it will only be large enough to enclose the `&nbsp;`  So without a specified size, it will only be responsive to the size of its content.

Therefore, you can set a percentage based upon the outer container, you can set a fixed height, or you can leave it out and allow content to dictate height.